# Changing subfunction c++

Tags: c++, function

I'm quite new to c++,
At the end of this program, I would like it to jump back an earlier subfunction allowing the user to input new values before providing new outputs in a later subfunction.
At the moment it will successfully return to the desired subfunction. However the program quits after it instead of continuing to the next subfunctions.

Here's the int main;

```
int main ()
{
welcome ();
input_dimensions ();
input_loading ();
transition ();
twodarray ();
initial_calculations ();
bending_stress ();
shearing_stress ();
bearing_stress ();
conclusion ();
cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

and heres the last subfunction

```
// C O N C L U S I O N
void conclusion ()
{
// End Results
cout << "\n\n\n____________ C O N C L U S I O N_____________ \n\n" << endl;

if ((bendingstress < designbending) && (shearstress < designshear) && ((  bearingstress <= (designbearing * kc90))))
{
    cout << "Beam is adequate for the input loads \n\n\n" << endl;
    cout << "\n\n\nPlease scroll up for more information \n\n\n" <<endl;
    cout << "\nPlease press ENTER to design a new beam or close this screen to quit" <<endl;
    system ("pause > nul");     
    system ("CLS");
    return input_dimensions (); 
}

else
{
    cout << "\n\n          W A R N I N G\n THIS BEAM IS AT RISK OF FAILURE ! \n" << endl;
    cout << "\nPlease scroll up for more information before trying new values \n" <<endl;
    cout << "\nOnce ready, please press ENTER to try new beam member properties \n" <<endl;
    system ("pause > nul");     
    system ("CLS");
    return input_dimensions (); 
}
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Also, `system("pause")` is a very inneficient way of waiting for a keystroke before continuing. `getch` & `getche` are much better options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However the program quits after it instead of continuing to the next
>   subfunctions.

- You call `input_dimensions()` inside `conclusion()`.
- When `input_dimensions()` return, execution will proceed at the next statement inside `conclusion()`.
- When `conclusion()` returns,
  execution will proceed in `main()` the statement after the call to `conclusion()`.
- There, you have three more statements inside `main()` to run, then your program exits.

C++ does not run statements more than once unless you tell it to, so the function calls in `main()` are only run one time only (you don't have any loops there).

Here is a possible solution to your problem:

Instead of having all the function calls in `main()`, you can make the functions call each other like this:

```
void welcome();
void input_dimenstions();
void conclusion ();
void initial_calculations ();

void welcome () {
     input_dimensions();
}
void input_dimensions () {
     initial_calculations();
}
void initial_calculations () {
     conclusion();
}
void conclusion () {
    if (...) {
              input_dimensions();
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    welcome();
}
```

This way you can control where to make the program go next inisde each function instead of letting `main()` do that, which usually gets messy really quick.

By declaring all functions at the top, you don't have to worry about the order of them later.